# Where did "WebSocket" comes from in restbed library example code?

Tags: c++, websocket, restbed

```
    #include <map>
    #include <chrono>
    #include <string>
    #include <cstring>
    #include <memory>
    #include <utility>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <restbed>
    #include <system_error>
    #include <openssl/sha.h>
    #include <openssl/hmac.h>
    #include <openssl/evp.h>
    #include <openssl/bio.h>
    #include <openssl/buffer.h>
    
    using namespace std;
    using namespace restbed;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    
    shared_ptr< Service > service = nullptr;
    
    map< string, shared_ptr< WebSocket > > sockets = { }; // What is this WebSocket ?
```

This code comes from restbed lib documentations WebSocket section. In this code, wondering that in line `map< string, shared_ptr< WebSocket > > sockets = { };`  where this WebSocket comes from, which namespace?

Comment: https://github.com/Corvusoft/restbed/blob/master/source/corvusoft/restbed/web_socket.hpp

Comment: But I get WebSocket was not declared in this scope error and I already have all of the libraries and frameworks.

Comment: If you have an error it's usually a good idea to mention that up front instead of asking where to find a particular class.

Comment: @mcel some circular inclusion problem maybe?